# Performance running ClearContents is very slow when WrapText is enabled in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I'm debugging the following code in an Excel 2007 VBA, which seems very simple.  For some reason its taking about 30 minutes to process 900 rows of data.  I think I have narrowed it down to some cell formatting, specifically the WrapText option.  Is there something I'm missing here that can increase the performance when deleting these rows.

```
Sub ClearContentsOfActive()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim NumLines
    NumLines = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Range("2:" & NumLines + 3).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Additionally, The user was not experiencing these delays in Excel 2003, with the same code.  Thanks in advance

### Update

In response to the redundancy of the ClearContents line, this is the original code that was working in Excel 2003, thats why I left it.  Commenting this line was one of the first things I tried, as I agreed that it may've been redundant.  See below for my psuedo perfomance metrics.

**Test1**

```
Selection.ClearContents  ''//  Takes ~30 mins
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp  ''// then this takes <1min
```

**Test2**

```
'Selection.ClearContents  '// If this line is commented
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp  ''// then this line takes ~30 mins
```

The reason I believe it has something to do with the WrapText feature is because when you clear the line of WrapText it performs and AutoFit operation on the row.  I thought that hiding screen updates or disabling events would help.

Comment: Which line takes long time to execute?

Comment: I added an update to my question

Comment: Is this an XLSX file which is causing the problem? Try saving it as XLS (2003 compatible) & see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Its an xls running in compatibility mode already.

Comment: Have you also tried starting a fresh Excel workbook and copying over this code? I have seen large Excel files become corrupt over time, especially if they are swapped between versions.

Comment: What kind of data it is? Does it fetch data from outside?

Comment: I tried the example with more than 1000 rows & 40 columns. It didn't take few seconds to finish.

Comment: Please put your findings, if you have the issue resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems to be related to the ColorIndex property of the cells and not the WrapText Feature.  The Macro for the page had the following code

```
For r = 0 to 1000
  For c = 0 to 15
    Sheets.Cells(r, c).ColorIndex = 14
  Next c
Next r
```

I recommended that the user uses ConditionalFormatting, junking the macro all together and that fixed his performance issues.

ConditionalFormatting was based on a formula on the entire sheet that turned the yellow if the following evaluated to true

```
=IF(ROW()>10, FALSE, LEN($A1)>0)
```

Comment: oh right so the conditional formatting was kicking in for each cell? thus blowing out the calc time? cool good to know something to look for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it actually necessary to call .ClearContents before calling .Delete? It seems to me that the call to .ClearContents is redundant. You're emptying the values in a range of cells that you simply remove from existence in the very next line.

I don't know if that will help with the performance issue, but it is worth a shot.

**edit:** In response to your update, how about avoiding the selction, and just doing the following:

```
Range("2:" & NumLines + 3).Delete shift:=xlUp
```

You can also try to get rid of the text wrapping ahead of time:

```
Range("2:" & NumLines + 3).WrapText = False
Range("2:" & NumLines + 3).Delete shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Fair enough. It was worth a shot :)